# How can I disable the "No Backups for x Days" from Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, notifications, high-sierra

Since I updated to High Sierra, I frequently get the "No Backups for x Days" notification. I used to be able to make this go away by turning off Time Machine in the System Preferences until I needed it, but there is no way to turn Time Machine off anymore. How can I get rid of these notifications?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For macOS 12 and earlier (pre-Ventura):

In the Time Machine preferences, you have to right-click on the drive icon and then select "Stop Using {Drive Name} for Backup".

[image: Time Machine Preferences Page, before Ventura]

For macOS 13 and later:

In Time Machine settings page, select the drive icon and click the [-] button at the bottom of the list.

[image: Time Machine Settings Page, Ventura]

Comment: I verified this. It is a good solution. To turn Time Machine back on, just select the backup disk again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get [TimeMachineEditor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/) and set your backup schedule to once a week or some time period you find more suitable. This app overrides the hourly backup default schedule of Time Machine and lets you define time periods to prohibit backups.