# Suppressing "no backups" messages from disconnected drives

Tags: backup, time-machine, notifications

I have three backup drives, but when traveling, I leave the bulkiest one in USA.  This trip, I also left one of the small ones.  I would like for MacOS to stop confronting me with "no backups" on the drives not connected.  Mildly inaccurate to say "no backups" when it really means "no backups on this particular drive."  But the unnecessary notices are more irritating than the trivial inaccuracy.

I can select "[Stop Using {Drive Name} for Backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303797/how-can-i-disable-the-no-backups-for-x-days-from-time-machine)" but that wording is also inaccurate.  It not only stops using, it removes the record of them having been used from the Pref pane.  I would really rather leave them showing in the preferences, along with when last used, and have it start using them as soon as I plug them in.  **Is that possible in 10.13.3?**